# Populating ListBox in Userform with Unique Values on workbook

Tags: vba, listbox, userform

I'm trying to populate a Listbox with unique values from Column P after populating the workbook through an activebutton. I've written the following syntax but for some reason it is only populating the ListBox with the first cells data but stops there.... Any ideas? I'm sure its something simple I'm missing as I'm new to VBA.

```
Dim Cellrng As Range
Dim Unique As New Collection
Dim Item As Range

On Error Resume Next
For Each Cellrng In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("START").Range("P8:P" & lRow)
    Unique.Add Cellrng, CStr(Cell)
Next Cellrng
On Error GoTo 0

For Each Item In Unique
   ListBox1.AddItem Item
Next Item
```

[image][image]

Comment: First off, remove `On Error Resume Next` - now does it give you any errors? Next, you need to give `lRow` a value. That cannot be `0` or blank, as there is no "row 0" - Next, you never define `Cell` or give it a value either, so you have many problems.

Comment: "This key is already associated with an element of this collection" - Highlights the "Unique.Add Cellrng, CStr (Cell)" line. I should have mentioned earlier, this block is running within a larger sub that has already given lRow the correct value.

Comment: Got it. Just needed to change the (Cell) to (Cellrng) - had a brain fart there. End of the day lol. TY for the help!

Comment: Save yourself some headaches and make sure you always use `Option Explicit` at the top of all code windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just needed to change (cell) to (Cellrng)

```
Dim Cellrng As Range
Dim Unique As New Collection
Dim Item As Range
Dim lRow As Integer

lRow = wkb.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).row
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Cellrng In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("START").Range("P8:P" & lRow)
        Unique.Add Cellrng, CStr(Cellrng)
    Next Cellrng
    On Error GoTo 0

For Each Item In Unique
   ListBox1.AddItem Item
Next Item
```

Comment: Fixed. Was already in my current Sub but I did not originally put it in my question.

Comment: Keep in mind that the answers are often used by other people in the future, so they need to be complete. This looks better.